# Append the value of several variables into a list at the same time

Tags: python

For example:

```
name   =       raw_input('Enter Part Name: ')
numid  = int(  raw_input('Enter NumId: '))
height = float(raw_input('Enter Height (in feet): '))
length = int(  raw_input('Enter Length: '))
```

Now I want to append them into a list called `NewInput`
Do I have to write four lines? Like:

```
NewIput=[]
NewInput.append(name)
NewInput.append(numid)
```

Is there any more simple way to do that?

Comment: no you can use `list.extend`

Comment: `NewIput = [name, numid, height, length]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `list1.extend(list2)`

```
NewInput.extend([name, Numid])
```

The difference in performance and readability is small so I don't think it makes much of a difference anyways.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! It works!

Answer (score 1):

Since your starting out with an empty list, why not just use this:

```
NewInput = [name, numdid, height, length]
```

If you have a list that already has entries then you can use the `+=` operator since lists are mutable.  For example:

```
NewInput += [name, numdid, height, length]
```

---

As an aside, you may want to consider using a dictionary instead of a list in this case.  I'm assuming you have a use case of querying the use for some useful information.  Why not store it in a more understandable and usable way.  For example, a dictionary:

```
new_input= {
    'name' = raw_input('Enter Part Name: '),  # raw_input --> input for Python 3
    'numid' = int(raw_input('Enter NumId: ')),
    'height' = float(raw_input('Enter Height (in feet): ')),
    'length' = int(raw_input('Enter Length: '))
}
```